# Is there a rule of thumb regarding the number of services which should run on a single instance of ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server

I have a single installation of ArcGIS Server serving all the GIS data for my organization, including internal and open data. It is installed on a Windows Server with 32GB RAM. We are up to well over 100 services. I currently have problems with image services failing, although map services seem to be stable. I cannot say for sure that by decreasing the amount of published services would increase performance or make the current services more stable as the network plays a role too.

How or when would I need to be thinking about running multiple instances of ArcGIS Server?

Comment: Sizing is a very difficult question to provide a simple answer too. It's generally a process of cataloging what you have and running it through sizing tools. But if I were force to provide an answer: 16GB RAM is probably not enough to serve 100 services. (assuming they're not pooled - pooled might be a stretch too). Are you at 98% RAM usage?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 32GB not 16GB as previously written. At 20.30 when everyone is not working on the network CPU as at 10%.

Comment: This is why this question is so difficult to answer. User load change. One service could have 1000 layers and the other 99 services could have a single layer. One service might be active at 8am, while others at 1pm. There are so many variables.